# Application Crash when calling Different Screens in MIT App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

I'm working in App Inventor, I have a main menu that contains twenty-two buttons.  The 20 will call the EmergencyHotlines screen (button 1 to 20) and the remaining will call the AnotherHotlines screen (button 21 and button 22).

When I try to test the application button 1 to 20 is working they were able to display the EmergencyHotlines screen.  But when pressing the button 21 or 22 the application crashes (displaying ***Application has stopped***) and then restart the application.

After the application restart, I select button 21 and 22 they working but the application crashes again (displaying ***Application has stopped***) when selecting either from button button 1 to 20.

Before instead of having two screens I tried to put them only on one screen.  They are all working except for button 21 and 22 and I having hard time to track the concern block.

I attached the screen capture of my block for your perusal.

[main screen calling the buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osUJj.jpg)[emergencyhotlines initialization setting the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQVeX.jpg)
[image]

[anotherhotlines initialization setting the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYrCR.jpg)
[image]

Comment: post your logcat here. We cannot help you until we get to the error causing the crash.

Comment: which exactly are the button click events, which fail? Do all screens exist? Remember: screen names are case sensitive...

Comment: I only see the concern when I build an apk of this project and then manually install them to my android.  Are there ways that we can get the logcat by these method?

Comment: the dDSWDButton and the dDOHButton fails.  Yes all screens do exists.  if only i can send the aia file to you guys for your perusal.